# How to use tensorflow js (tfjs) from typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tensorflow.js

I've tried to install typings:

```
npm install --save @type/tfjs
npm install --save @type/tenforflowjs
npm install --save @type/tensorflow
```

But it doesn't exist. On [tensorflow js github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs) I can see that it is developed using Typescript, but it seems they did not distribute definitions. If there is no definition distribution (I hope I am wrong), how can I use their github repository to obtain it and still benefit from their future releases?

Comment: `npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs` should be all you need. The type definitions are included.

Comment: @ExplosionPills it worked, thank you. You should put it as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that there is unfortunately no simple way to tell whether types are available in a library since type definitions can be exported in a variety of ways.

If you do `npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs`, you will see that there is a `node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/index.d.ts`. Additionally in the [`package.json` for the project, there is `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/package.json#L11).

That is to say types are available for this library.

If types are not included with the package, you can check [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/) to see if there is a third party definition available at `@types/{package}`. Otherwise you'll be on your own for strong typing.

Comment: But that `.d.ts` file only links to several other `.d.ts` files. There are more than 10 `.d.ts` files in the whole node_modules folder. Are they all needed if you want to work with typescript?

Comment: I guess you need to build the project, and then a single `.d.ts` file is generated in the `dist` folder?

Comment: If you import from `@tensorflow/tfjs` it should use the .d.ts files that are there as well. This shouldn't require any additional setup.

Comment: True! But then you need the whole node_modules folder. I would prefer a single .d.ts file, just to get typescript intellisense for Tensorflow. I still load tensorflow itself using the script tag, without using a module build process.

Answer (score 3):

to install `tensorflow.js` run:

```
npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs
```

to import to your `*.ts` file do:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
```

> still troubles?
>
> make sure `tsconfig.json` has `"compilerOptions"` with `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Answer (score 0):

You can include a javascript file in you typescript project where you include exclusively which is related to tensorflow. All the proprocessing -that is the heavy part- and the classification or regression result, can be done in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing as you did.

Simply import the module and run `npm install`. No need to install types.

Worked for me!